# При обращении к php появляется ошибка что невозможно загрузить динамическую библиотеку «mysqli»

Tags: php, ubuntu

Использую Ubuntu 20.04 lts.При обращении к php появляется ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_get_client_info), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне их можно обновить или добавить?

Comment: последний раз когда доводилось настраивать сервер на убунту - все компоненты ставились из коробки через apt, и было это чтоб не соврать пару месяцев назад. в любом случае вы можете скачать указанные библиотеки отдельно и доставить их, пути все есть в сообщениях об ошибках

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep mysql` - вывод команды в вопрос добавьте.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы! Решил не мудрствовать и переустановил пакет php.